# Amazon ASIN - Amazon Standard Item Number

Tags: android, amazon-product-api, amazon-appstore

Well i am trying to find what does ASIN mean what is being used for while publishing android app to Amazon store.

I found couple of links pointing to what ASIN stands for, Amazon Standard Identification Numbers (ASINs)  or Amazon Standard Item Number. i am confused !!! i need this ASIN to add it in Manifest file.

Below are some links that i have checked it :

[Link 1 where you can See the ASIN in product details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B2V66VS)

[Link 2 where it says how we can get the ASIN and what is ASIN](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200202190)

The above links shows how we can get ASIN once we have app on Amazon store but since i have not submitted the app till now how will i find ASIN in my app ?

Comment: Why do you need it now? Wait until it's published.

Comment: @Parker we need that ASIN to be mentioned in other SDK that we have integrated.

Comment: @Parker sorry i didnt get you

Comment: Ok,Yes i need the ASIN for my app but its not yet published to store before that how can i find the ASIN number ?

Comment: Where in the Amazon API does it say you need it before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63460/discussion-between-user2056563-and-parker).

Comment: Please update your question with detail

Comment: Which API are you using? I can't imagine they've created a catch:22 like this without a solution

Comment: @Offbeatmammal i am using a third party API for that we need to add ASIN in the manifest file.

Comment: can you submit an earlier build, get the asin then publish the update? Also, what API? do they have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi! I have the same question as you - did you manage to get the ASIN before publishing the app? For the others that are asking why would you need it: because in the app you may have a share link which must point to the application in the market and the way to do this is to embed the link in the code, and that happens before publishing. So if you publish like before getting ASIN, the share link will not work.

Comment: @Lyuben If we submitting the app for the very first time then we will not get the ASIN number, so only after we publish the app we get the ASIN number, for the next updates we can use the ASIN number.

Answer (score 1):

A very late answer here just incase anyone else has this problem like I had. Amazon's developer page has provided a helpful guide of what you can do to get around this: https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/deep-linking-to-the-amazon-client

Comment: link is invalid